# SVG not showing up on Safari en Chrome in current CSS (solutions found here not working)

Tags: html, css, svg

Been struggling with what will probably be basic things for most of you (I'm pretty new to all of this). I had made a page with a logo and a basic hover effect on an image, using an img tag. Seemed to work on all browsers. I then changed the image to an svg format to preserve definition for the effect. Works fine on Chrome as far as I can see, but not on explorer, nor Safari (couldn't test Firefox yet). I tried different tags (img, object, iframe), but on Safari and Explorer my svg just refuses to show up. You can see the page here: [www.hardnose.be](http://www.hardnose.be)

Use Chrome to see what the intention is (for other browsers).

To make matters worse, I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50dfpsdL/1/) for you guys, and it gets screwed up completely. I don't know why, because I'm pretty sure I just copied the source and changed the image link to my domain, so you guys could see it. So I guess my code isn't that great to begin with. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

HTML

```
<html>
<body>    
    <div class="logo">
       <a>
          <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/LogoWhiteSmallText.svg">
             <img src="http://hardnose.be/images/LogoWhiteSmallText.svg" alt="Hardnose Logo" target="_blank">
          </object>
       </a>
    </div>            
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif; }

/* line 28, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.1/css/index.scss */
body {
  background: #6ca66b;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #6ca66b, #3398cc);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #6ca66b, #3398cc);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #6ca66b, #3398cc);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6ca66b, #3398cc);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */ }

/* line 41, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.1/css/index.scss */
object {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 1; }

/* line 54, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.1/css/index.scss */
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: top; }
  /* line 62, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.1/css/index.scss */
  .logo :hover {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 0.5s ease; }

/* line 73, /Users/Inkidu/Documents/Hardnose/Website/v2.1/css/index.scss */


/*# sourceMappingURL=index.css.map */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're trying to do with your shark ? 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpGeVG

It works on IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Let me explain it. First, HTML :

```
<div class="logo">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.hardnose.be/images/LogoWhiteSmallText.svg" alt="Hardnose Logo" />
  </a>
</div>
```

I don't think you need the `object` tag. At least not for the placement and effect you want to achieve.

The `.logo` block will perform the positioning. You can have the same result without it, positioning the link directly, but I kept most of your HTML structure unchanged.

The link will perform the action once you specify it with `href` or `onclick` attribute. FYI, `target` is not an attribute of `img`, but of an hypertext link.

Finally, the image inside, loading your SVG file.

Then, the CSS :

```
html { height: 100% }
body {
  background-color: #3398cc; /* Use gradient here instead */
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 129px; height: 60px;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
.logo img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 100%; 
}
.logo img:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

I strongly advise you not to use `*` selector. At least at the beginning. Define your CSS properties on each element to keep control of what you're doing.

As you see, the `logo` block is used to position the link at the center of your screen. And finally, you just have to specify the opacity of your image and it's aspect change on hover.

Comment: Yes, you're codepen example is exactly what I'm going for! It seemed to work on Chrome (hardnose.be) in the same way your code shows up. Thanks for all the tips! I'll go through it tonight and see if it solves the svg problem.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Thanks a lot!